# how to switch 'find as I type' user prefference in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, keyboard, shortcut

I want to create a keyboard shortcut using Keyconfig addon that will switch on/off the 'find as I type' feature.

I have created the new shortcut with this is the code inside:

```
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService);
var branch = prefs.getBranch("accessibility.");
var x = branch.getBoolPref("typeaheadfind");
user_pref ("accessibility.typeaheadfind", !x);
```

Unfortunately it is not working.

How can this be done using either keyboard shortcut or extra button in toolbar?